# Add files to multiple tables M:N

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-key-relationship, multiple-tables

What is The best Data model for Add multiple files to The multiple tables? I have for example 5 tables articles, blogs, posts... and for each item I would like to store multiple files. Files table contains only filepaths (not physicaly files).

Example:
[image]

Im using The links table, but when I create in the future The new table for example "comments", then I need to add new column to The links table.

Is there a better way of modeling such data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use the table inheritance pattern. The main idea is to have a base table (let's call it `content`) with general shared information about all the items (e.g., creation date) and most importantly, the relationship with files. Then, you may add additional content types in the future without having to worry about their relation to `files`, since the `content` parent type already handles it.

E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE flies (
    id NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY,
    path VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE content (
    id NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY,
    created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE links (
    file_id NUMERIC NOT NULL REFERENCES files(id),
    content_id NUMERIC NOT NULL REFERENCES content(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (file_id, content_id)
);

CREATE TABLE articles (
     id NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES content(id),
     title VARCHAR(400),
     subtitle VARCHAR(400)
);

-- etc...
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Table articles, PK Id is referenced to content. IT means for each article will be created 1 row in content. For each content table (articles, posts, ...) will be created 1 row in content and files will be Linked to this rows with links table. Does I understand correct?

Comment: For compare, does exists another solution?

Comment: @steelbull yes. Think of content as the "abstract parent class" of all concrete content types, such as articles, blogs, etc.

Comment: I was try your solution. Its very Nice, but does exists possibility to automatically Generate The id on articles, posts... Tables?